# Proper way of setting up a gulpfile.ts

Tags: typescript, gulp

I've set up a `gulpfile.ts` for my project following this example right [here on GitHub](https://github.com/kolorobot/angular2-typescript-gulp/blob/master/gulpfile.ts). (I will not supply my `gulpfile.ts`, since it's basically the same, just a little bit more complex)

Whenever I ran a gulp task, I got these 4 errors:

```
[11:53:23] Failed to load external module ts-node/register
[11:53:23] Failed to load external module typescript-node/register
[11:53:23] Failed to load external module typescript-register
[11:53:23] Failed to load external module typescript-require
```

I then decided to add `ts-node` as a (local) dev-dependency. (Global installation did not change anything)

After `npm install` and running a gulp task, I then got some typescript errors like this

```
gulpfile.ts (19,23): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
```

I did not find anything on google on how to solve this issue, but after having a look on some example `gulpfile.ts` files, I came across a kind of a workaround. Adding this line:

```
declare var __dirname, require;
```

on top of my `gulpfile.ts` solved the issue and I am not getting any error messages anymore. However, this seems to be a dirty hack somehow.

**So here's my question**: Is this a legit way of setting up a `gulpfile.ts`?

I also took a look at gulpclass files using typings and everything, but I think that this is pretty much of an overkill for a simple build file, isn't it? What are your suggestions? What are the best practices for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a legit way of setting up a gulpfile.ts?

Yes that will work and people do do that. However I recommend you also bring `node.d.ts` into your project. `typings install dt~node --global` will do the trick.

Comment: Do I need to `/// <reference ...>` `node.d.ts` then? I will try that as soon as I have time, thank you for your response.

Comment: `Do I need to /// <reference ...> node.d.ts then` Yes. Here is an example : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/269b8285387f5a7fdf1a2d2aafa40e96a425576d/Gulpfile.ts#L1

Comment: Thank you, a way better solution than defining those vars :)